# Is it possible to use a smartphone/tablet's 3G/4G network to transfer Eyefi photos?

Tags: file-transfer, smartphone, apps, tablet, eye-fi

I know that Eyefi cards can use Wi-Fi networks to transfers photos. I also know that there's some sort of smartphone/tablet app that you can download to do various things with your Eyefi card and photos, but in the case that a Wi-Fi connection is not available, can the Eyefi card somehow link to a smartphone/tablet and use that smartphone/tablet's 3G/4G network to transfer the photos to a predesignated computer? Thank you.

Comment: I never thought of this angle. I do believe its possible (I provided an answer). This makes EyeFi an even more attractive option that I need to try.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could turn your device into a Wifi hotspot and then EyeFi can connect to the internet via your phone (or tablet).

I don't have any experience with Eye Fi specifically, but presumably its programmed to scan for a list of known wifi hotspots. I would imagine you could program it to find your phone consistently and then once your device is enabled as a hotspot and as long as your phone has internet access to the target machine (ie. that target machine needs to be exposed to the www as a server of some sort) you'd be off to the races.

Of course enabling your device as a wifi hotspot will eat up data usage from your cell plan, so make sure you've covered that angle. If your plan doesn't already include data it can be a pretty sizable hit to the wallet.

A quick Google search turned up these pages:

- [2 easy ways to turn your Android phone into a wifi hotspot](http://www.wikihow.com/Turn-Your-Android-Phone-Into-a-Wi%E2%80%90Fi-Hotspot)
- [How to set up your iPhone as a Wi-Fi mobile hotspot](http://www.phonearena.com/news/How-to-set-up-your-iPhone-as-a-Wi-Fi-mobile-hotspot-iOS-9-tutorial_id50579)

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

From the [specs](http://www.eyefi.com/products) I could not see any kind of 3G/4G compatibility, therefore I don't think EyeFi can be used with these kinds of networks. Should they decide to offer such a product, it would have to include a nanoSIM, a wi-fi transmitter and the memory itself, which is quite an effort in that tiny space.
Anyway, no network in the whole world would support unlimited full-speed download/upload of huge amount of data (provided you shoot in jpeg maximum quality a photo is more or less 10 Mb), so I guess nowadays it would be useless to include a 3G/4G module in EyeFi cards...

EDIT: Sorry I misunderstood your question. If [you can manage to make EyeFi selectively](https://x2help.eyefi.com/hc/en-us/articles/448606-Add-a-Wireless-Network) connect to a Wi-Fi network (I am sure that it doesn't only connect to open Wi-Fi, but you can set which one to connect to), you can of course use your tablet or mobile as a tethering hotspot. Basically the EyeFi would connect to your phone/tablet with Wi-Fi as if the last one it was a router. 3G/4G connection would then be used to link your EyeFi to the internet

Comment: I think HartleySan's idea is to use a WiFi connection between a tablet or a phone to transfer the photos from the Eyefi to the phone and then use the phone 3G capacity...

Comment: I highly doubt that you know about every mobile data plan in the world so you cant say that "network in the whole world would support unlimited full-speed download/upload of huge amount of data". Also JPEG is a bad example since it's the raw files that are the huge files. Also the conclusion that 3G/4G modules would be useless is unsubstantiated. This could have a huge application for journalists for example.

Comment: First of all, I work in the telecommunication field and I know how the networks operators think. Tell me ONE example of carrier which does not limit bandwidth or volume. So yes, I think I can generalize for the time being.
Second: you don't know if he is shooting RAW and of course JPEG would be a "best case scenario"

Comment: @Noldor130884 No problem! I worked in a Swedish company and we used "Telenor 4G premium 80 Mbit" dataplan. It's unlimited (can be slowed down if a lot of users are using it in the same area but as soon as it clears it's full speed again) and we regularly exceeded 900 GB data a month and no hint of being capped. Sure you can argue that the limitation in crowded areas is a bandwidth cap, but that is a consequence of the 4G networks design and not the plan. If I were to go to a lesser dense area I could use it at full speed all month.

Comment: Noldor, thank you for your edit. I have a basic understanding of the limitations at play here, but I was more just curious if it was even hypothetically possible with a smartphone/tablet. Luckily, it is. Thank you very much. Further investigation is now required.

Comment: @Hugo: You don't have any "fair use" clause? I was in fact not talking about network capacity, but about limitations to the "all you can eat" approach.

Comment: @Noldor130884 Perhaps it has, but it didn't matter since we never hit the roof. My point was that given that huge dataplans exist the 3G/4G module isn't useless. Don't know how big the market would be, but you have to shoot a lot of pictures to end up in the hundreds of gigabytes range.