# How to send photos from camera to tablet while shooting for immediate viewing?

Tags: tethering, image-review, tablet, nikon-d80

How can I connect my Nikon D80 camera to my tablet? I would like for the photos to go directly to the tablet as I am shooting them so I can view and make adjustments. I recently saw it done by a wedding photographer and it would be very helpful for my future shoots.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to automatically transfer photos from a DSLR to a PC hard disk as they are taken?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/20299/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-transfer-photos-from-a-dslr-to-a-pc-hard-disk-as)

Comment: See also http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/70095/is-it-possible-to-use-a-smartphone-tablets-3g-4g-network-to-transfer-eyefi-phot?rq=1

Comment: And http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/69889/wirelessly-transfer-photos-from-camera-to-a-computer?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You can use an EyeFi SD card, which contains a wifi radio, to wirelessly connect to your tablet. [The Nikon D80 is supported by Eye-Fi cards](http://www.eyefi.com/cameras#nikon/d80).

Note: I *highly* recommend only buying a newer EyeFi Mobi or Mobi Pro card. All other Eye-Fi cards (X2, etc.) have been discontinued by Eye-Fi, and will no longer work with their online service EyeFi Cloud (which was recently sold to Ricoh) after September 2016.

- [Ricoh Is Buying EyeFi Cloud, But Not Their SD Cards](http://resourcemagonline.com/2016/06/ricoh-is-buying-eyefi-cloud-but-not-their-sd-cards/67952/)
- [Eyefi To Brick Its Older Wi-Fi Cards, And Photographers Aren’t Happy](http://petapixel.com/2016/06/30/eye-fi-brick-older-wi-fi-cards-photographer-arent-happy/)

Comment: Please note that Eye-fi cards will create their own network which will have a non-negligible impact on battery life. Transferring pictures happens in one of two modes: You can have the card send everything to the tablet, which can be slow depending on how you shoot, or you can have it send only photos selected for printing to the tablet. The latter option requires configuration of the card with the desktop software beforehand though. You cannot change this behaviour on the fly.

Comment: @Roland not true. You can have your phone/table/laptop/3G router create the network.

Answer (score 1):

Nikon has an app called The Wireless Mobile Utility which allows you to take pictures and view them on [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nikon.wu.wmau&hl=en) and [Apple](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wireless-mobile-utility/id554157010?mt=8) devices. If your camera doesn't have built in wifi you will need a wireless adapter to interface with your device.